# Is Rama a Jagadguru?

Tags: krishna, rama

Krishna is popularly called as Jagadguru.

Rama is also an purnavathara of Vishnu. Why he is generally not called as Jagadguru? Is it true that he is Jagadguru?

Comment: Rama did not do Upadesha through words. He did upadesha through action.

Comment: First, he 'walked-the-walk' as Rama, then he 'talked-the-talk' as Krishna. If someone asks why Rama avatara first and Krishna avatara later, it's because Bhagavan knows that if he first did Gita-upadesha, immediately some smart-fellow will ask 'Did you practice what you preach?', and to answer that he can say 'Look at when I came to earth previously as Rama'. That's why Krishna is *called* jagad-guru, but Rama is real/first jagad-guru because actions speak louder than words.

Comment: btw, for those who may be confused, rama,krishna,vishnu are just different names of bhagavan depending on time/circumstances, just like you are called 'betaa' by parents, 'papa' by children... they are referring to same paramatma

Comment: rAmo vigrahavAn dharmah, says the Valmiki Ramayana. Rama is the embodiment of dharma. If you can give a form to dharma, that form would be Rama. Rama is the biggest mystery of hinduism, in my opinion. A human being or a god? - I wonder.

Comment: Some of the wonderful qualities of Rama are described by Valmiki here -  https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga1/ayodhya_1_frame.htm

Answer (score 2):

Yes.Rama is Jagadguru.

> **Raama**-naama sada premna samsmaraami **jagadgurum**/kshanam na bismritim yanti satyam satyam vacho mama// (O Arjuma! I always remember with love the name of Rama, the Jagadguru and do not forget for a moment (Adi-Purana, quoted in Omkarnath Rachanavali, vol 11, page 424)

All the qualities of Jagadguru are also explicitly mentioned i Sri Ramastakam:

> Nija-Swarupa-bodhakam Kripa-karam Bhava-apaham/... bhaje ha Ramam Advayam meaning I worship Rama, Who **awakens the sense of the real Self, bestows grace, removes the bondages of the worldliness.**..these are the Qualities of Jagad-Guru.

Comment: What are Adi-Purana and Omkarnath Rachanavali? @Partha

Comment: @hanugm Sitaaramdas Omkarnath was a famous saint from Bengal knownnacross the globe.Youncould find Him on wikipedia and net.Adi-Purana is the name of a Purana.

Comment: @hanugm partha, who is speaking here? If it is Krishna speaking, this Rama would be Balaram most likely..

Comment: @MohMur no its about RAMA as Omkarnathji included it in Rama-naama-mahima-amrita.

Comment: @MohMur and other features of RAMA are mentioned.

Comment: @hanugm partha, ramastakam and adi purana verses are from different sources. Rama also can be called jagadguru he is same Krishna. But I think this adi purana verse is not referring to Rama.

Comment: @MohMur chanting of the name of Balarama is never that important in our tradition. Rama can mean Parasu-Rama too.But in our culture, by Rama name we man the name of the Tretayuga Rama. Sitaramdas Omkarnathji besides being a saint was a sankrit scholar Himself.Pl read about him on wiki and diff online sites